# Setting Up a Buy X Product, Get Y Product Free

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart

I would like to set up a "Buy X Product, Get Y Product Free" rule on Magento. Can anyone show me how to do this?

Comment: Look at Magento doc here http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rule-shopping-cart-buy-x-get-y-free.html

Answer (score 0):

Writing out the whole process would take an excessive amount of space here, so here's a video (word a thousand words) that details it perfectly for you on how to "Buy X quantity of product, get Y quantity for free".

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnYgXiy7JkE